# My python code doesn't work

Tags: python

Struggling to work out why python complaining at line 4:

```
import sys
import re
problem = input("What is wrong with your mobile device?").lower
water = re.search(r'water', problem)
screen = re.search(r'screen', problem)+ re.search(r'smashed',problem)or re.search(r'cracked',problem)+ re.search(r'display',problem)
software=re.search(r'software',problem)+ re.search(r'program',problem)
keypad=re.search(r'keypad',problem)+ re.search(r'keyboard',problem)+ re.search(r'text',problem)
speakers=re.search(r'sound',problem)+ re.search(r"can't here",problem)+ re.search(r'cant hear',problem)
microphone=re.search(r'microphone',problem)+ re.search(r'cant hear me',problem)+ re.search(r"can't hear me",problem)
battery=re.search(r'battery',problem)+ re.search(r'swollen',problem)
charger=re.search(r'Charger',problem)+ re.search(r'charge',problem)+ re.search(r'charging',problem)
if water:
    print("If your phone has suffered water dammage there is not much you can do, it is recomended that you buy a new phone")
    sys.exit
elif screen:
    print("If your screen is cracked then it is recomended that you get it repaired this is not too expensive.")
    sys.exit
elif software:
    print("If you have a software issue then contact the product manurfacture, they are the only ones qualified to fix this.")
    sys.exit
elif keypad:
    print("Clean your keypad with a wetwipe, do not get the charger port or jack port wet.")
    sys.exit
elif microphone:
    print("Your microphone hole may be blocked, please clean this with a soft dry tooth brush, if this does not work then please retern the hand held device to its manufactures.")
    sys.exit
elif battery:
    print("If your battery is enlarged/swollen you have probbaly over charged it it is recomended that you buy a ned battery.")
    sys.exit
elif speakers:
    print("The speaker on most phone is located on the side or back or the device if this is blocked then please attemt to clean this with a dry, soft toothbrush, if this does not work please contact the product manurfacture.")
    sys.exit
elif charger:
    print("If you have not tryed buying a new charger then try that. If a new charger does not work, please send your mobile device to the product manurfacture.")
    sys.exit
else:
    print("please write your problem again, attempt to use keywords that relate to your problem.")
    sys.exit
```

If someone could tell me how to correct this or correct this themselves it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please check your formatting before posting; your current code is unreadable (use Ctrl+K to get indented code blocks which are formatted properly). Also, please include the *full* error message so we can see it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

you are not calling the function lower in line 3. In order to call it, you have to write 2 parenthesis after it. Thus, correct that line as follows:

```
problem = input("What is wrong with your mobile device?").lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually on line 3. According to [this article](http://sweetme.at/2014/01/22/how-to-get-user-input-from-the-command-line-in-a-python-script/), Python 2 uses `raw_input` to get input, while Python 3 uses `input`. It looks like your code is expecting a Python 3 environment, but your environment is actually Python 2.

You can replace your call to `input` with a call to `raw_input` if you are, indeed, running in a Python 2 environment.

In addition, you must use parentheses after the call to `lower` so that the method actually gets called.

### Python 2

```
problem = raw_input("What is wrong with your mobile device?").lower()
```

### Python 3

```
problem = input("What is wrong with your mobile device?").lower()
```

Comment: I don't really think that is the problem

Comment: @Jalo, it depends on if it's Python 2 or 3. If he's running in Python 2, then my solution would fix it (without needing to add parentheses at the end of the call to `lower`). If it's Python 3, then you're right

Comment: The solution I posted works equally on Python 2 and Python 3. The difference is that with input function the user needs to enclose the input with quotes

Comment: Anyway, parentheses are mandatory for calling the lower function

Comment: @Jalo In Python 2, the method call `input` [evaluates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915408/899126) what gets provided as an expression. You could add quotes around it, and asking your users to do that each time would be pretty rough ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting you. I am discussing about the **lower** function, not the input / raw_input functions. In order to use (call) the lower function, you have to use parentheses. If not you will only be assigning the function itself to the  variable

Comment: @Jalo I stand corrected; I could've sworn that, with Python open, I had called `.lower` and had it work. Do you know a good glasses place nearby, because apparently I need a pair

Comment: haha don't worry. Actually I guess I am much newbier than you are, and I was wondering were could I be failing. Problem solved then :)